# Why is index.html returned by Asp net Core for requests of my Angular Spa dist files?

Tags: angular, iis, asp.net-core, url-rewriting, kestrel

After deploying my Asp Net Core Angular Spa to a shared web server, requests for the angular runtime components return my index.html file.

EDIT (rephrasing question to clarity):

I have an angular spa that is served by the asp net core angular template. When I navigate to the url for the application, the index page is returned and then subsequent calls to return the script files for the client app all return index.html as well... even though the url is requesting runtime.js, main.js, etc

What additional configuration is required in addition to my code excerpts below?

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc();

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
    }); 
}
```

In my angular.json, I specify the following URL prefixes:

```
"baseHref": "/APPNAME/",
"deployUrl": "/APPNAME/ClientApp/dist/"
```

The source tree appears to be correct.

The requests for each of the runtime components are successful but they all return my index.html rather than what was requested.

Request URL: https://example.com/MYAPP/ClientApp/dist/main.17cf96a7a0252eeecd9e.js

Response from Chrome network debugger:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>APP NAME</title>

  <base href="/APPNAME/">

  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"
        name="viewport">
  <link href="HRDRicon.png"
        rel="icon"
        type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/APPNAME/ClientApp/dist/styles.d9e374eff45177231bee.css"></head>
<body class="fixed-sn white-skin">

<app-root></app-root>

<noscript>
  <p>
    Sorry, JavaScript must be enabled to use this app
  </p>
</noscript>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/APPNAME/ClientApp/dist/runtime.e460f84ccfdac0ca4695.js">
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="/APPNAME/ClientApp/dist/polyfills.d0cb8e9b276e2da96ffb.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/APPNAME/ClientApp/dist/scripts.a54ea6f0498a1f421af9.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/APPNAME/ClientApp/dist/main.17cf96a7a0252eeecd9e.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I will add a link to the images in a comment since that is restricted in the original post.

Comment: Debugger screenshots: https://i.imgur.com/n0mSAzj.png, https://i.imgur.com/qnFueiW.png, https://i.imgur.com/8DKVtZS.png

Comment: If you are deploying your application to the same domain as your services; middleware is not necessary.

Comment: I rephrased my original title question. My assumption was that there needed to be some middleware to default requests to the right asset. If I dont need middleware, can you think of another reason why the links to my script files in index.html all return a response of index.html? Let me know if I need to include further details. Thanks!

Comment: To answer your question, the app is an intranet application that includes the api services and requests for the client app.

Comment: Based on the screenshots and the code, I don't really understand what the problem is.

Comment: I have an angular spa that is served by the asp net core angular template. When I navigate to the url for the application, the index page is returned and then subsequent calls to return the script files for the client app all return index.html as well... even though the url is requesting runtime.js, main.js, etc

Comment: So instead of getting index.html and main.js, polyfills, runtime, styles, for my client app. Index.html loads and then loads index.html again for all the references to other static resources like script files

Comment: Sounds like a server config issue or something to me, but am unclear why that would be.  Can you load the js files directly? Are there any redirect rules in place?  Are the proper mimetypes set up for JS / CSS files?

Comment: I cannot load the JS files directly. I do not have any redirects set up and have done nothing with mimetypes.

Comment: To me this sounds like a server/IIS configuration issue, but I don't think I'm suited to direct you further.

Comment: Appreciate the input Jeff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I struggled with the spa-extensions, too. It seems that `UseSpa` sets up a catch-all rule to index.html that also intercepts the requests to all static files like .js and .css.
To get my spa working in a subdirectory, all that was required were the modifications 1. and 2. in the startup.cs. No spa-extensions required.

```cs
public static void Configure( IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // ...
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    // 1. Configure request path for app static files
    var fileExtensionProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
    fileExtensionProvider.Mappings[".webmanifest"] = "application/manifest+json";
    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
    {
        ContentTypeProvider = fileExtensionProvider,
        RequestPath = "/myapp",
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"MyApp/dist"))
    });

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization(); 

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        // 2. Setup fallback to index.html for all app-routes
        endpoints.MapFallbackToFile( @"/myapp/{*path:nonfile}", @"MyApp/dist/index.html");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my configuration, I have an ASP.Net Core 5 project with an angular app deployed to a folder called ng under the wwwroot folder

[image]

I need to serve the index.html by default when deep linked from /ng and I also need to serve other non angular content from /

To achieve this I added two static file configurations, one for angular and one for regular files

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
...
    FileExtensionContentTypeProvider contentTypes = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
                contentTypes.Mappings[".apk"] = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";
                app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
                {
                    ContentTypeProvider = contentTypes
                });
    
                var fileExtensionProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
                fileExtensionProvider.Mappings[".webmanifest"] = "application/manifest+json";
                app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
                {
                    ContentTypeProvider = fileExtensionProvider,
                    RequestPath = "/ng",
                    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot/ng"))
                });
```

(The extra apk config is to allow users to download android packages direct)

Al also needed to set up the endpoint fallback to index.html for the /ng/ url

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile(@"/ng/{*path:nonfile}", @"ng/index.html");
            });
```

and of course in the angular in the index.html the base href is set to ng

[image]